# Convert present Datagrid data into DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

How to convert present Datagrid data into a DataTable? I have filtered the datagrid now i want only filtered data into a datatable. Datagrid.ItemSource or DatagridView is not helping here.

Comment: What was the original source of the data? i.e. what is the DataGrid bound to?

Comment: What returns `datagrid1.ItemsSource.GetType().Name;`?

Comment: What you are using ASP.net or Winform application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put data from datagrid to datatble as:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        DataColumn[] dcs = new DataColumn[]{};  

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgv.Columns)  
        {  
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();  
            dc.ColumnName = c.Name;  
            dc.DataType = c.ValueType;  
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);  

        }  

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgv.Rows)  
        {  
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();  

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in r.Cells)  
            {  
                drow[cell.OwningColumn.Name] = cell.Value;  
            }  

            dt.Rows.Add(drow);  
        }
```

Comment: I have only datagrid. I dont ve datagridview.

Comment: I dont have dgv here. Want to convert present datagrid items into datatable

Answer (score 1):

Persist the updated data in session or write it in XML and take data whenever you want.

Some thing like this

```
 private void BindGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["GridData"] == null)
        {
            dt = GetData();//From database or and other source
            Session["GridData"] = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];
        }

        GridView.datasource = dt;
        GridView.Databind();
    }

    private void UpdataData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["GridData"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];


        // Do whatever you want with dt (datatable);
        Session["GridData"] = dt;

        BindGrid();
       }

    }
```